# Irish Short-stay Visa Waiver Programme

Tags: visas, ireland

Update: Actually I successful entered Ireland on 5th of August (direct flight from Paris to Dublin) with my valid and used UK visa. The immigration officer gave me 90 days of stay. So actually if someone has entered UK at least once, they he/she avails the Short-stay visa waiver programme can go to Ireland from a third country instead of the UK.

I'm a Chinese citizen and I have a valid UK standard visitor visa for 6 months till October 2022. I've been to the UK (London) in May 2022 and went back to Paris where I live for the moment. I plan to visit Dublin in August 2022, do I avail the Irish Short-stay Visa Waiver Programme? If so, can I book the flight directly to Dublin or I have to enter the UK first then flight to Dublin?

Comment: How long did you spend in the UK? Was it the same/similar to the visit length you stated in your visa application? UK visitor visas are multiple entry, valid for 6 months *but* that does not mean you are guaranteed entry on a return trip

Comment: Note that you can always apply for an Irish visa for free if you have a Schengen residence card.

Comment: You should write you newly added Update as an answer and accept it. This makes it easier for others who have the same problem and are looking for the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the rules, to enter Ireland on the basis of a valid UK visa, you must first enter the UK.

From https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/short-stay-visa-waiver-programme/ :

“You may be able to visit Ireland, for less than 90 days, without an Irish visa if you can answer “yes” to each of these questions:

Do you have an eligible UK short stay visa?

and

Does your visit to Ireland end before your permission to stay in UK ends (this is granted by an UK immigration official when you pass through UK immigration)?”

You exited the UK and returned to France, thereby ending your permission to stay in the UK. Therefore you cannot answer ‘yes’ to the second question.

Comment: In what way does leaving the UK end your permission to stay in the UK?

Comment: @Sneftel Because a UK visa is not ‘permission to stay’ in itself. On arrival a visa holder gets a stamp permitting them to enter the UK. Once the individual leaves the UK that specific permission ends, although the visa itself remains valid and the holder can seek further permission(s) to enter up until the expiry date of the visa.

Comment: Though a transit in UK could result in a new leave to enter.

Comment: Thank you that's clear i understood that part, i think it's better to cancel the trip and avoid the risk.