# Is a UK visit visa applicable for Ireland also?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I have a UK visa, which I took recently to visit London. Can Ireland be included in the trip? Or does a separate visa need to be taken for that visit?

Comment: https://www.dfa.ie/travel/visas/visas-for-ireland/

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175262/irish-short-stay-visa-waiver-programme

Comment: Can you tell us your citizenship?

Comment: Indian Citizen, resident of Singapore

Answer (score 4):

The general rule is that you would need a separate visa.

There are however exceptions:

- One is a waiver for certain nationalities (including citizens of India) if they meet some specific conditions outlined [here](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/short-stay-visa-waiver-programme/).

  You need to have entered the UK first and still be before the end of the permission to stay granted on entry to the UK. This should work for you.
- The other, which applies to nationals of India and China who reside there, is the British-Irish Visa Scheme, described [here](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/british-irish-visa-scheme/).

  If your visa has a “BIVS” endorsement, then you can travel to the Republic of Ireland without requiring an additional visa.

  Note that there a specific requirements (like entering the country which delivered the visa first, or the case of single-entry visas), so read the page linked above carefully.

  The fact that you are resident in Singapore excludes the BIVS scheme in your case.

Finally, for completeness, this only applies to the Republic of Ireland. Northern Ireland is part of the UK and you don’t need an additional visa or a BIVS endorsement to travel there.

Comment: Indian and Chinese nationals (among others) may also visit Ireland under the short stay visa waiver program if they have first entered the UK and obtained leave to enter. Unlike BIVS, which usually is only available to Chinese and Indian resident nationals, this is a unilateral Irish concession available regardless if the UK visa is issued under BIVS.

Comment: @xngtng Ah, I had missed India and China in the list for the visa waiver. Updated the answer.